# How to use core location in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I've done a bit of research but I'm still not sure how to use core location within swift. I don't understand the location manager and the delegates and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple important things to understand about corelocation conceptually.

1. Import the corelocation package, this will give you access to everything in the corelocation framework
2. Create a CLLocationManager object. This is the main class necessary for using corelocation.
3. Adopt the corelocation protocol and set the location manager delegate to whatever class adopted the corelocation protocol.
4. Request for the users permission. This is necessary because of apple privacy guidelines. Make sure to also add a location when in use/always usage key in your info.plist()
5. Implement the error and didupatelocations method
6. You can call location manager.requestLocation() and get the location.

Overall these are the main steps hope this helps.

Also in the future make sure to do more research before asking a question. There are a ton of good YouTube videos and articles that explain corelocation. Apple documentation is also very helpful.